# Resizing Pictures with RxJS and Node

Tags: node.js, rxjs, graphicsmagick, rxjs5

I'm new to RxJS and trying this (seemingly) simple task, but I just can't figure it out.

I want:
1.  Read an image from file
2.  Convert that image to several smaller images
3.  Save all images to file

I've converted fs.readFile and fs.writeFile to observables.

```
const readFile$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
const writeFile$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.writeFile);
```

I made a pictures array pipeline.

```
var pictureSizes = [
  {width: 100, size: 'thumbnail', suffix: '_t'},
  {width: 300, size: 'small', suffix: '_s'},
  {width: 600, size: 'medium', suffix: '_m'},
  {width: 1000, size: 'large', suffix: '_l'}
];
```

And I made a resizeImage$ function using graphics magic

```
function resizeImage$(picture, data) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      gm(data)
        .resize(picture.width)
        .toBuffer('jpg', function(err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            observer.next(buffer);
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
  })
}
```

I think (hope) the above is ok.  I can't figure out how to chain my operators.

```
  readFile$('./largeimage.jpg')
    .mergeMap(data => pictureSizes.map(picture => resizeImage$(picture, data)))
    .flatMap(picture => writeFile$('./testImages/resized.jpg', picture))
    .subscribe(
    (x) => console.log('Next', x),
    (e) => console.log('Error', e),
    (c) => console.log('Complete',c )
  )
```

This above corrupted data to a jpeg file.  (And rewrites that file because I can't figure out how to get pictureSizes.suffix into the outputted file name.

Anything helps!  Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I got it to work, but I know this bizarre multiple subscription is a horrid anti pattern.  The main subscription completes before the image is resized.  I have a feeling this is a hot/cold issue, but I have no idea how to fix it.  Here's my now working code..

```
const pictureSizes = [
  {width: 100, size: 'thumbnail', suffix: '_t'},
  {width: 300, size: 'small', suffix: '_s'},
  {width: 600, size: 'medium', suffix: '_m'},
  {width: 1000, size: 'large', suffix: '_l'}
];

const image = 'truck.jpg';

function resizeImage$(binary, pictureSize) {
  return new Rx.Observable(observer => {
      gm(binary)
        .resize(pictureSize.width)
        .toBuffer('jpg', function(err, buffer) {
          console.log('BUFFER');
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            observer.next({binary: buffer, pictureSize: pictureSize});
            observer.complete('done');
          }
        });
  }).subscribe(
    (resizedImage) => {
      console.log(resizedImage);
      const binary = resizedImage.binary;
      const pictureSize = resizedImage.pictureSize;
      const fileName = image.split('.')[0];
      const fileExtension = image.split('.')[1];
      fs.writeFile(`./testImages/${fileName}${pictureSize.suffix}.${fileExtension}`, binary);
    })
}
  var readFile$ = new  Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
  readFile$(`./${image}`)
  .zip(Rx.Observable.of(pictureSizes), (binary, sizes) =>
        Rx.Observable.of({ binary: binary, sizes: sizes }))
  .mergeMap(x => x.value.sizes.map(pictureSize => 
       resizeImage$(x.value.binary, pictureSize)))
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: Are you saying that what you have is working except for applying the file suffix? As a test, if you comment out all of the `pictureSizes` except for one, do get a valid, non-corrupted output file?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I wasn't clear... The file suffix is an additional problem.  The end file is corrupted with only one pictureSize objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example I think you can further simplify your answer:

```
var pictureSizes = [
  {width: 100, size: 'thumbnail', suffix: '_t'},
  {width: 300, size: 'small', suffix: '_s'},
  {width: 600, size: 'medium', suffix: '_m'},
  {width: 1000, size: 'large', suffix: '_l'}
];

const scaler$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback((binary, size, callback) => {
  gm(binary)
   .resize(size.width)
   .toBuffer('jpg', callback);
});

const readFile$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
const writeFile$ = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.writeFile);

function scaleImage$(sizes) {
  const scales = Rx.Observable.from(sizes);

  return source => 
    source.flatMap(binary => 
      scales.flatMap(
        size => scaler$(binary, size),
        (pictureSize, binary) => ({pictureSize, binary})
      )
    );
}

function resize(imagePath, sizes) {
  return readFile$(imagePath)
    .let(scaleImage$(sizes))
    .flatMap(result => {
      const {pictureSize, binary} = result;
      const [name, ext] = image.split('.');
      return writeFile$(`./resized/${name}${pictureSize.suffix}.${ext}`, binary);
    });
}
```

Use:

```
resize(imagePath, pictureSizes)
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Wow!  This will take a second to wrap my head around it.  Two questions.  Two functions use "sizes" as an argument, but I don't see it defined.  Is that "pictureSizes"?  And two, with RxJS 5, can I substitute mergeMap for your FlatMap?

Comment: Whoops I used the wrong variable name, yes, the `sizes` are the `pictureSizes`. And yes you could substitute that, I think the `mergeMap` alias still exists. I believe that the RxJS 5 project is moving back over to `flatMap` name though, so `mergeMap` may become deprecated at some point in the future.

Comment: That worked brilliantly.  It made a lot more sense then the mess that I made.    I'm still trying to understand the currying source => source.flatMap wizardry.    I feel like once I can figure that out, my programming will greatly improve.  Thank you for your time and great work!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I have an answer.  If anyone would like to refactor it further, please do so.

Remaining questions...
1.  Should the write file be done as an observable to catch errors?
2.  I'm not sure why mergeAll was needed.

```
var pictureSizes = [
  {width: 100, size: 'thumbnail', suffix: '_t'},
  {width: 300, size: 'small', suffix: '_s'},
  {width: 600, size: 'medium', suffix: '_m'},
  {width: 1000, size: 'large', suffix: '_l'}
];

function scaleImage$(binary, pictureSize) {
  return new Rx.Observable(observer => {
      gm(binary)
        .resize(pictureSize.width)
        .toBuffer('jpg', function(err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            observer.next({ binary: buffer, pictureSize: pictureSize });
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
  })
}

function writeFile(binary, pictureSize, image) {
  const fileName = image.split('.')[0];
  const fileExtension = image.split('.')[1];
  fs.writeFile(`./resized/${fileName}${pictureSize.suffix}.${fileExtension}`, binary);
}

function resizeImage(imagePath) {
  var readFile$ = new  Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);
  readFile$(imagePath)
    .combineLatest(Rx.Observable.of(pictureSizes),(binary,y) => y.map(pictureSize => Object.assign({}, {binary, pictureSize} )))
    .mergeMap(arr => arr.map(obj => scaleImage$(obj.binary, obj.pictureSize)))
    .mergeAll()
    .subscribe((obj) => writeFile(obj.binary, obj.pictureSize, image))

}
```

And if you want synchronous behavior (scale image 1 -> write image 1 -> scale image 2 ...), use concatMap and concatAll.